# actionButtonStyle doesn't work with support lib v23.1.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

With latest support lib release (v23.1.0) I noticed that one of the theme attributes doesn't work for me anymore. Im using `actionButtonStyle` theme attribute for customizing action buttons in Toolbar:

```
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ......
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton</item>
    ......
</style>

<style name="Custom.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

It works perfectly fine with support lib v23.0.1, but doesn't work with v23.1.0 anymore.

So the question is - is this is a right way of customizing toolbar action buttons? And if not, what's the right way of doing it with latest support lib release?

Tried to ask first party (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191544) - but got a "we don't care" response :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start to understand why there is this issue in the v7 support library v23.1.0.

`AppCompatTextHelper` v23.0.1:

```
// Now check TextAppearance's textAllCaps value
if (ap != -1) {
    TypedArray appearance = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ap, R.styleable.TextAppearance);
    if (appearance.hasValue(R.styleable.TextAppearance_textAllCaps)) {
        setAllCaps(appearance.getBoolean(R.styleable.TextAppearance_textAllCaps, false));
    }
    appearance.recycle();
}

// Now read the style's value
a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, TEXT_APPEARANCE_ATTRS, defStyleAttr, 0);
if (a.hasValue(0)) {
    setAllCaps(a.getBoolean(0, false));
}
a.recycle();
```

`AppCompatTextHelper` v23.1.0:

```
// Now check TextAppearance's textAllCaps value
if (ap != -1) {
    TypedArray appearance = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ap, R.styleable.TextAppearance);
    if (appearance.hasValue(R.styleable.TextAppearance_textAllCaps)) {
        setAllCaps(appearance.getBoolean(R.styleable.TextAppearance_textAllCaps, false));
    }
    appearance.recycle();
}

// Now read the style's value
a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, TEXT_APPEARANCE_ATTRS, defStyleAttr, 0);
if (a.getBoolean(0, false)) {
    setAllCaps(true);
}
a.recycle();
```

As you can see in v23.1.0 `setAllCaps` will be called only if the style's value is `true`. This is why when the value is `false` nothing happens. In previous version `setAllCaps` is called every time there was a value.

How to restore the attribute `textAllCaps` like version 23.0.1?

Add these rows to styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/Custom.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Apply the theme to your toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>
```